# cakephp model with hasmany

Tags: cakephp, activerecord, has-many, cakephp-model

I have question in cakephp model,

I want to add dynamic condition in var $hasMany keyword

I want to add condition like current user_id, i got user Id after my login.

```
var $hasMany = array(
    "AskComment"=>array('limit'=>3),
    'AskStatistic',
    'AskContactsLink',
    'AskStatistic',
    'AskObject',
    'AskLikes'
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add dynamic condition in your model, then you might have to bind the model association-ship dynamically into your controller's code. Write the following code into your controller's method for which you want to impose some new condition on the existing/new associated models.

```
$this->PrimaryModel->bindModel(array('hasMany' => array(
    'AskComment' => array(
        'className' => 'AskComment',
             'foreignKey' => 'primary_id',
              'conditions' => array('AskComment.user_id' => $user_id)
         )
    )
));
```

Take a look at this link: [Creating and destroying associations on the fly](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#creating-and-destroying-associations-on-the-fly). This will surely help you to achieve the same.

Comment: `bindModel(...)` only applies to the next find operation. Use `bindModel(..., false)` to create a persistent association (for all subsequent finds in the request)

Comment: If we want to make the persisted model associations based on some conditions in a controller level, then we can define the above association in `beforeFilter() method` of respected controller. Your are right @ori. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to put your association in the **construct function** of your **Model**.
like this:

```
/**
 * @see Model::__construct
 */
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'AskComment' => array(
            'className' => 'AskComment',
            'foreignKey' => 'primary_id',
            'conditions' => array(
                'AskComment.user_id' => $user_id,
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```